# AR(2) & constant & trend - very poor constant estimates?

Tags: r, time-series, arima

Here is a problem that was puzzling me. Suppose I simulate the AR(2) process with constant and trend using the code below (I apologize for inefficiency and inelegance - the aim was to get job done at this point; also - it may seem strangely constructed, but it has some other purpose too for which is irrelevant here).

My question is - why the constant estimates are so poor? The true value is `70` but if we average 1000 regressions each over 1000 observations I get an average of `381.9234`.

Is it because I interpret something wrong or the did I make a mistake somwhere?

```
set.key(123)

#parameter values
V=7
P=10
S=4
r1 = 50/(50+P)
r2 = V/(30+V)
mu = 10*P
l2 = 10*(S+V)
a0 = 10*V
d0 = 10*P
a1 = 0
d1 = P+V
s2 = 2*(P+V+S)

#simulate and estimate the parameters
data<-NULL
data50 <- NULL

for (firm in 1:1000){

  y_zero <- rnorm(1, mean = mu, sd = l2)
  gamma_0 <- rnorm(1, mean = a0, sd = d0)
  gamma_1 <- rnorm(1, mean = a1, sd = d1)

  y_first <- r1*y_zero + gamma_0 + gamma_1 + rnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = s2)
  y_second <- r1*y_first - r2*(y_first - y_zero) + gamma_0 + 2*gamma_1 + rnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = s2)
  y_third <- r1*y_second - r2*(y_second - y_first) + gamma_0 + 3*gamma_1 + rnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = s2)
  y_fourth <- r1*y_third - r2*(y_third - y_second) + gamma_0 + 4*gamma_1 + rnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = s2)

  column <- cbind("firm" = firm, "t" = 1:4, "y" = c(y_first, y_second, y_third, y_fourth))

  data <- rbind(data, column)
  ###################################################################################
  firm50 <- NULL

  y_fifth <- r1*y_fourth - r2*(y_fourth - y_third) + gamma_0 + 5*gamma_1 + rnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = s2)
  y_sixth <- r1*y_fifth - r2*(y_fifth - y_fourth) + gamma_0 + 6*gamma_1 + rnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = s2)

  y_previous1 <- y_sixth
  y_previous2 <- y_fifth

  firm50 <- cbind("firm" = firm, "t" = c(5,6), "y" = c(y_fifth, y_sixth), "ro1-ro2" = c(y_fourth, y_fifth), "ro2" = c(y_third, y_fourth))

  for (run in 1:5000){
    time <- run + 6

    the_y <- r1 * y_previous1 - r2 * (y_previous1 - y_previous2) + gamma_0 + time*gamma_1 + rnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = s2)

    firm50 <- rbind(firm50, cbind("firm" = firm, "t" = time, "y" = the_y, "ro1-ro2" = y_previous1, "ro2" = y_previous2))

    y_previous2 <- y_previous1
    y_previous1 <- the_y

  }
  firm50 <- cbind(firm50, "gamma0" = gamma_0, "gamma1" = gamma_1)
  data50 <- rbind(data50, firm50)
}

#estimate the coefficients
data <- data.table(as.data.frame(data50))[t %in% c(4000:5000)]
coefs <- NULL
for(i in 1:1000){
  coefs <- rbind(coefs, t(coef(arima(data[firm==i, y], c(2,0,0), xreg = data[firm==i, t])))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something wrong with the `arima` function that I probably misinterpreted, because when I estimate the same model using `lm` the estimates are much more reasonable!